# write a recursive function that takes and integer and returns "True' if all of its digits are prime numbers

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a Python recursive function that takes an integer as an argument and returns `True` if all of its digits are prime numbers.
   e.g.

```
    allPrime(976)
      False
    allPrime(357)
      True
```

This is what I've done so far

```
def allPrime(n):
    h=str(n)
    for i in range(len(h)):
        if h[i] == isPrime(h):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Come on, there isn't even a question here. If you want people to do your homework, at least be creative about it.

Comment: And what aspect of the task are you stuck on?

Comment: you don't have to convert it as a string...
you can do it with modulo and division by 10.
also, your function is not recursive

Comment: @clph3r - That's not recursive, agreed, but there's some idiots who think recursion and repetition are the same and even teach that. I've read at least one published book (admittedly about VBScript, IIRC) that claimed that recursion was written using `for` loops. For the record, sure there's a mathematical equivalence - recursion can be rewritten as repetition and visa-versa - but that doesn't mean they're the same thing. Similarly, binary and decimal aren't the same thing just because any binary number can be converted to decimal and visa versa. The form you actually used is significant too.

Answer (score 0):

```
def allPrime(n):
    if n==0:
        return(True)
    elif (n%10) in [2,3,5,7]:
        return(allPrime(n//10))
    else:
        return(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you just have to extract the last digit, check if it is a prime and continue with the rest.

Writing a recursion basically consists of a trivial case and a recursion, where you break down the problem into a smaller one until you are in a trivial case.

So, what you need to do is, find your trivial case, where no further recursion is needed, and think about how to achieve this:

```
#separate the number (123) into a last Digit (3) and the rest (12)
lastDigit = n % 10
rest = int(n / 10)
```

if we have a none-prime, we can return False and not goint further into a recursion:

```
if not isPrime(lastDigit):
    return False
```

The trivial part is just one digit, therefore the non-trivial part is this, where we go into recursion:

```
if n > 10:
    return allPrime(rest)
```

so we have the case, where we stop because of a non-prime, we have the non-trivial-case
the trivial case does not go into recursion either, and because we already had the case where we have a non-prime, we just need:

```
return True
```

**sum it up:**

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    if n == 2: return True
    if n & 1 == 0: return False
    for x in range(3, int(n ** 0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


def allPrime(n):

    lastDigit = n % 10
    rest = int(n / 10)
    if not isPrime(lastDigit):
        return False
    if n > 10:
        return allPrime(rest)

    return True



print(allPrime(9777))
print(allPrime(773))
```